# EPSON Scanner software times out after 15 minutes of inactivity

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, printer, scanner, epson-workforce

An EPSON multi-function printer/scanner is installed on the same WiFi network as a Windows 7 computer.

After 15 minutes of inactivity, the EPSON scanner software will generate a fatal time-out error message box.  When clicking on the message box, the EPSON scanner software closes.

I'm trying to prevent this from happening.  My fist step was to see if the EPSON software was being blocked at all by a firewall.  It was, and I temporarily allowed necessary connections.

But the issue persists.  What is the next step to diagnose this issue in order to prevent the time-out error?

Comment: Most printers and all-in-ones put themselves to sleep after a period of inactivity.  Could the action you're seeing be driven by the all-in-one going to sleep (as opposed to something on the computer side)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks.  That's an interesting possibility.  How do I tell if it's asleep or awake?  The device's LCD screen is off even when it's awake and waiting for a command from a computer to perform a scan.  In other words, the outward appearance is the same whether it's asleep or awake.  People say that about most of us lizards as well. ;)

Comment: That's like how can you tell male goldfish from female goldfish? See whether they eat male or female goldfish food. How do you tell whether its male or female goldfish food? That's a different question for a different expert; I already answered the question you asked.  :-)  With some printers, the display will go out quickly. If you send another job to it within a few minutes, it will start immediately. After some period of idle, it will do stuff like clean and park the printhead. If you then send it another job, it may go through a startup cycle of cleaning the printhead (cont'd)

Comment: (never miss an opportunity to use ink), and cycling the head back and forth. It may do something similar with the scanner if you've scanned but not printed. If there hasn't been too much delay, it may be immediately ready for the next scan. But if it's parked the scan head, it may do a quick calibration cycle. If there's that kind of indicator, it's a good bet the device went to sleep, and the software may just be reacting to that. If the all-in-one doesn't go through those behaviors, there wouldn't be much to go on. In that case, you'll need to find an expert on goldfish food.

Comment: LOL! I needed that smile! :)  Besides a great anecdote, I think you're on to something. Sometimes, when the scanner software is opened, the device will make some sounds (perhaps the document feeder turning it's gears); other times, it doesn't. I hypothesize that it is asleep, and being awakened, when it makes this sound. I need to test it out more, but I think you've figured it out.  Let's assume it is going to sleep, and that causes the EPSON software to generate a fatal error... besides preventing the device from sleeping, would there be any way to keep the software from abending like this?

Comment: I haven't got a clue.  :-)

Comment: You should start by adding the actual model number of the scanner/printer to the question.